# Angular 10 path aliases issue

Tags: angular, typescript, eclipse

I am trying to use path aliases for services & components so that I can avoid messy imports. My services are under src/app/services folder. I have an AppService file app.service.ts. I added below code in tsconfig.json.

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src/app",
        "paths": {
          "@services/*": ["services/*"]
  },
```

and I imported service in my component class like

```
import { AppService } from '@services/app.service';
```

It doesn't work. It throws error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/app.service' or its corresponding type declarations. What is wrong here?

Comment: I would generally leave the baseUrl as `'.'` and use 'src/app/services'. 
Also, when generating a lib angular creates two path aliases, one without wildcard ( `"@services": ["src/app/services"]` ) as well as the one with a wildcard ( `"@services/*": ["src/app/services/*"] ` ). In theory yours should work though, hope it helps. Consider adding an `index.ts` file at the root of `services` so then you can `import {...} from '@services'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still receive the same error message. ```{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@services/*": ["src/app/services/*"]
  },```

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything to tsconfig.base.json and I put the below line in tsconfig.json. It works!

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
}
```